# How to extract data from a LONG column holding XML strings

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle10g, extract, ora-00997

Here is my table

```
MYTABLE(ID NUMBER(10),
        DATATYPE VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
        XMLDATA LONG
)
```

Note1: I cannot alter this table
Note2: I'm using Oracle 10g

Here is a sample of XMLDATA

```
<myxml version="1">
  <node1>
   <child1>value to get</child1>
  </node1>
</myxml>
```

I tried xmltype() but it's not working with a LONG type (ORA-00997 illegal use of LONG type). Maybe I should copy XMLDATA values to a new table and convert to a CLOB then I can convert to xmltype and use [EXTRACTVALUE()](http://www.psoug.org/reference/xml_functions.html)?

What is the best way to extract 'value to get' ?

Comment: long is obsolete, use clob or the new xml types.

Comment: @tuinstoel: See Note1 in the text. Table can't be altered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is some code that is supposed to output a CLOB from a LONG of arbitrary length.  It dumps the body of `MY_TRIGGER` to `dbms_output`. If it works you should be able to parse that as needed.

```
DECLARE
    c_chunk_limit CONSTANT   INTEGER := 100;

    v_cur                    INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
    v_offset                 INTEGER;
    v_chunk                  VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_chunk_size             INTEGER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_SQL.parse(
        v_cur,
        'SELECT trigger_body FROM dba_triggers WHERE trigger_name = ''MY_TRIGGER''',
        DBMS_SQL.native
    );

    DBMS_SQL.define_column_long(v_cur, 1);  -- 1 here represents the column position in the select list the long is column#1

    IF DBMS_SQL.execute_and_fetch(v_cur) > 0
    THEN
        v_offset   := 0;

        LOOP
            DBMS_SQL.column_value_long(
                v_cur,
                1,  -- 1 here represents the column position in the select list the long is column#1
                c_chunk_limit,
                v_offset,
                v_chunk,
                v_chunk_size
            );

            EXIT WHEN v_chunk_size = 0;

            v_offset   := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_chunk);
        END LOOP;
    END IF;

    DBMS_SQL.close_cursor(v_cur);
END;
/
```

Comment: +1 for the example. If anyone still needs convincing that Oracle LONG is evil, this should do it :-)